# why DELETE Key APDU command returns 6A80 Status words?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I'm going to delete an existent key from my card's ISD. To do so I sent a DELETE Key APDU command with corresponding KeyID and KeyVersion to the ISD after a successful Mutual Authentication as below:

```
-->  00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 00
<--  6F 5B 84 08 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 00 A5 4F 73 49 06 07 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 01 60 0B 06 09 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 02 02 02 63 09 06 07 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 03 64 0B 06 09 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 04 02 55 65 0B 06 09 2A 86 48 86 FC 6B 02 01 03 66 0C 06 0A 2B 06 01 04 01 2A 02 6E 01 03 9F 65 01 FF 90 00

-->  80 50 00 00 08 79 71 01 3C 63 9D 72 A3
<--  00 00 90 30 09 0A 90 72 3D A3 01 02 00 00 60 AD 80 68 C2 A1 79 AE B9 E4 4A 4D B7 99 90 00

-->  84 82 00 00 10 AB E9 10 5B 60 7C DE C6 9C DC 15 E0 DA 9B 81 44
<--  90 00

-->  80 E4 00 00 06 D0 01 01 D2 01 71
<--  6A 80
```

As you see above, I received `6A80` status word which means *Wrong Data*. I've have tried the same command and data with a different card and it successfully returned `90 00` status words.

So

1. What is wrong with this card and how I can delete this key?
2. Is there anyway to list all existent keys on the card? As far as I know, GET DATA APDU command with *Tag 66* (Key Information Template) does not return list of all available keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Some card are simply not supporting it. As alternative you can rotate the keys to a random value.
2. The tag for key templates is 00E0. You can use this with GET DATA. E.g. [GPShell](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform/blob/master/gpshell/src/gpshell.1.md) provides the command `get_key_information_templates -keyTemplate index`. Use 0 as index. This output returns a more readable list.