# Why I fail to delete or replace inserted Receipt Key with KeyVersion=0x70 in the Javacard?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I have a clean [Kona112](https://konai.com/business/cards/card) Javacard and I'm going to a put a Receipt key into it and then I want to delete it from the card or replace its value.

**Step 1:** I tried to create a new key on the card with `Key Version == 0x71` (Quoted from GP UICC Configuration v1.0.1: "Key Version number '71' with Key Identifier '01' is reserved for the Receipt Key, which is a DES key"):

```
[Select ISD]

[Successful Mutual Authentication]

-->  84 D8 00 01 1F 71 80 10 B5 75 C3 8D 89 DC F9 B1 74 CC 1E 93 C4 45 C8 2C 03 CD 80 0F EC EA 8D 6F 8F BF 7D D0 // PUT KEY
<--  6A 80 

==> Quoted from GP UICC Configuration v1.0.1: "6A80 = ISO compliant standard status word for Algorithm not supported"
```

**Step 2:** As I received "Algorithm not supported" error, I enabled Delegated Management on my card and retried step #1:

```
[Select ISD]

[Successful Mutual Authentication]

[Proprietary APDU command to enable Delegated Management]

-->  84 D8 00 01 1F 71 80 10 1A F6 96 45 2A ED 66 86 75 DF FC 8B 59 55 6D 0B 03 CD 80 0F 87 03 E4 1A 8D AB 90 EC
<--  71 CD 80 0F 90 00
```

Good! I successfully put the Receipt key in the card.

**Step 3:**  Now, I want to delete it:

```
[Select ISD]

[Successful Mutual Authentication]

-->  80 E4 00 00 06 D0 01 01 D2 01 71 // Delete APDU Command to delete a key with Key ID = 01 and Key Version = 71
<--  6A 80
```

As you see above, I received `6A 80` error status words. It is mentioned in the answer of [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65422876/why-delete-key-apdu-command-returns-6a80-status-words/65424747#65424747) (and also in GP UICC Configuration v1.0.1) that the *Key Deletion* feature is optional.

So in step #4 I tried to replace the key with another value.

**Step 4:** I changed P1 in PUT Key APDU command from `0x00` (create key) to `0x71` (overwrite):

```
[Select ISD]

[Successful Mutual Authentication]

-->  84 D8 71 01 1F 71 80 10 E9 06 6B 8E D8 05 50 34 D5 A7 71 3B 81 CB BE 7A 03 CD 80 0F 91 0D BC E9 96 25 7E 89
<--  6A 88
==> Quoted from GP UICC Configuration v1.0.1: "6A88 = Referenced data not found"
```

Well, that's weird, I received "Referenced data not found". So I tried the PUT Key command with `P1 = 0X00` (Create Key) again:

```
[Select ISD]

[Successful Mutual Authentication]

-->  84 D8 00 01 1F 71 80 10 31 35 5C 0C E3 27 FD D5 8B 6B AE 37 56 CA 0D F2 03 CD 80 0F 0B EB 16 CF FF CE 4C 09
<--  69 85 // Conditions of used not satisfied.
```

Well, I tried both cases of step #3 (`P1 = 0x00` and `P1 = 0x71`) with disabled *Delegated Management* too, but nothing changed and I respectively received 0x6A80 and 0x6A88.

**What's wrong?  How can I fix the delete or modify this key?**

Note that I tried all the steps in secure channel with SecurityLevel = 0x03 too. Nothing changed.

**Update:**

I tried to list the available keys in the card using GET DATA APDU command with Key Info Template tag, but I only can see ISD ENC, MAC and KEK keys in the APDU Response (For both DM enabled and DM Disabled.

```
--> 80 CA 00 E0 00
<-- E0 12 C0 04 01 01 80 10 C0 04 02 01 80 10 C0 04 03 01 80 10 90 00
```

Comment: Is the key listed when using GET DATA with the key template tag?

Answer (score 0):

One idea: The receipt key (and you also have to store a token key) might be linked to a application security domain. Select the Security Domain with Token Verification privilege and the Security Domain with Receipt Generation
privilege, maybe they are different from the ISD. I assume also that during `[Proprietary APDU command to enable Delegated Management]` a new application security domain (ASP) was created. Try the select these new security domains and list there all the keys using the key template flag and execute then your `PUT KEY` operations against one of these security domains. `GET STATUS`is the command to be used for listing the SDs. All the existing OS tools like GPShell and GlobalPlatformPro can do this.